# Customer icon notification:android

Tags: android

Can please add a badge to a notification icon like it appear in this image(in the red cercle)[image]

thanks for advance

Comment: Check out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html.  You can specify whatever icon you want.

Comment: I want to put a number inside the icon of my notification.This number can be changed all the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `number` field:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#number

Comment: Note that this does not work for all devices and all versions of Android.